# Give one column what it needs, give the other column everything else

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set up a page with a left sidebar and then the rest of the content to the right of it. All of the examples I have seen use `<div>` tags with the `display:table` and `display:table-cell` attributes and then either specify widths (in pixels) for both the sidebar and the content area, or, at the very least, the sidebar.

In my case, what is going to be in the sidebar is not known ahead of time. All I know is that it won't "want" to take up very much width (ie, through short lines and line-breaks, the entire corpus shouldn't be very wide). So, I don't want to specify the width of the sidebar.

How can I make the sidebar `<div>` to automatically snap tight to the widest elements contained within, and then have the content `<div>` act as a column which spans from the right edge of the sidebar to the right side of the page.

Comment: What's the problem with `display: table-cell`?

Comment: What, for that matter, is the problem with not specifying a width and leaving it at that? Add some padding maybe, a border possibly, but the browser will style its width according to what it needs.

Comment: @MechanicaUK: Personally, I don't have a problem with using it... but I can't get it to do what I want.

Comment: @ArtOfCode: I have textual menus for the sidebar. I don't want the sidebar to take up more space than it has to. I want to be able to change the text in the menus without having to experiment with different sidebar widths until I find the right one. Most importantly, I want to be able to change the font size of the sidebar text on a whim without worrying that it's going to look like a mess because the sidebar is, suddenly, too narrow. Now that I've justified my reason for wanting this behavior, *now* will you tell me how to do it?

Comment: @Jemenake: if you read my comment you would know already.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: table-cell`, which is especially useful if you want both areas to have the same height, but also to make them fill up the width.

Part of the table behaviour, is that it resizes cells to fit content. So you can just set the width of the sidebar cell to a very small value and it will be as small as possible, still resizing to the minimum size it needs for it's contents. This is not different for CSS tables:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="column side">Side test content</div>
  <div class="column content">Main content</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.column {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.side {
    width: 1%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5bro1n06/

Comment: Okay... I should have been more careful with my wording. I don't want to give the sidebar what it *needs*, I want to give it what it *wants* and nothing more. For example:
http://jsfiddle.net/jemenake/5are6v29/
Notice how the menu lines get clobbered? This will happen even if you ommit "width:1%" from the "side" style. Sure, I could just replace every space with &nbsp's, but I seek a method which is less of a hack.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to utilize the css float if you don't want to use table elements

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="column side">
    Menu Item 1<br/>
  </div>
  <div class="column content">
    lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    position:relative;
}
.column {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.side {
    float: left;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    border-right: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Your updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5are6v29/2/
Like others have said, there is nothing wrong with using display: table-cell but I prefer my way for columns as it usually leaves my markup cleaner and easier to read.